# Hi Update the particular value using the email field in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, sfdc

I want to Update the particular Record Based on the Email Id Please Help me to Solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Record Id To Update the particulate record value using work bench
Use Data Loader to Update the particular record field

For Your Below Reference

https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php